# python ElementTree decoding error

Tags: python, xml, encoding

I've got an [`ElementTree`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) instance I'm trying to output to text using the [`tostring`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.tostring) method:

```
tostring(root, encoding='UTF-8')
```

I get a `UnicodeDecodeError` (traceback below) because one of the `Element.text` nodes has the `u'\u2014'` character. I set the text property as follows:

```
my_str = u'\u2014'
el.text = my_str.encode('UTF-8')
```

**How can I successfully serialize the tree to text?** Am I encoding the nodes incorrectly? Thanks.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "crisis_app/converters/to_xml.py", line 129, in convert
    return tostring(root, encoding='UTF-8')
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1127, in tostring
    ElementTree(element).write(file, encoding, method=method)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 821, in write
    serialize(write, self._root, encoding, qnames, namespaces)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 940, in _serialize_xml
    _serialize_xml(write, e, encoding, qnames, None)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 940, in _serialize_xml
    _serialize_xml(write, e, encoding, qnames, None)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 940, in _serialize_xml
    _serialize_xml(write, e, encoding, qnames, None)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 938, in _serialize_xml
    write(_escape_cdata(text, encoding))
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1074, in _escape_cdata
    return text.encode(encoding, "xmlcharrefreplace")
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 288: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: The message says it's trying to decode it as ASCII, not UTF-8.  Also, 0xE2 doesn't seem to be related to 0x2014 (em-dash).

Comment: Can we see some more code? It appears that you non-unicode text in your tree, which causes the `text.encode()` to first **decode** to Unicode in order to then encode again.

Comment: @JimGarrison yes, it is related indeed, this is the utf-8 representation of em-dash: `0xE2 0x80 0x94 (e28094)` 0xE2 is the first byte. http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2014/index.htm

Comment: Well then, something is trying to interpret the UTF-8 as ASCII...

Comment: @JimGarrison the problem is i'm calling the library function w/ the encoding set to UTF-8, and if you look where it's throwing the error, it looks like it's trying to encode w/ ascii.

Comment: @MartijnPieters i'll try to boil it down to a smaller test case.

Comment: I had a similar error, because I specified `utf8` instead of `utf-8` as encoding. Maybe this comment can help somebody.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do this:

```
my_str = u'\u2014'
el.text = my_str.encode('UTF-8')
```

you're setting the text to an utf-8 encoded version of the unicode character. It's the same as

```
el.text = '\xe2\x80\x94'
```

Now you don't have an unicode character anymore, but a series of bytes.

If you then do:

```
tostring(root, encoding='UTF-8')
```

You're saying you want the content encoded as utf-8. To to that, internally the string has first to be decoded to unicode using the default encoding (ascii), and then encode as utf-8, which of course fails as the bytes in the string arn't in the ascii range.

ElementTree is perfectly capable of working with unicode, so just give it unicode instead of str:

```
>>> from xml.etree import ElementTree as et
>>> e = et.Element('test')
>>> e.text = u'\u2014'

>>> s = et.tostring(e)
>>> print s, repr(s)
<test>&#8212;</test> '<test>&#8212;</test>'

>>> s = et.tostring(e, encoding='utf-8')
>>> print s, repr(s)
<test>—</test> '<test>\xe2\x80\x94</test>'
```

Comment: yea turns out the problem was i was calling `el.text = str(content)` on everything just in case `content` was an int. this was throwing errors, so my fix had a logic error that ended up double-encoding the output.